# How can I make my website communicate with my servlet?

Tags: java, ajax, html, servlets

I've created a web app that gets the JqTree "coordinates" and send these coordinates `var POSITIONS` to my server to be gotten by my servlet that will create a file containing those "coordinates", however, **I don't know how I am going to make this communication**. Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

I made kind of a chart right below explaining my idea.

**1 - The user changes the tree**
[image]

**2 - The positions are immediately gotten by this code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var POSITIONS;

//var data is a dynamic JSON file that should be created in the backend.
var data = [{
    label: 'node1',
    id: 1,
    children: [{
        label: 'child1',
        id: 2
    }, {
        label: 'child2',
        id: 3
    }]
}, {
    label: 'node2',
    id: 4,
    children: [{
        label: 'child3',
        id: 5
    }]
}];
$('#tree1').tree({
    data: data,
    autoOpen: true,
    dragAndDrop: true
});


console.log($('#tree1').tree('toJson')); //This will give you the loading jqtree structure.

$('#tree1').bind(
    'tree.move',
    function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do the move first, and _then_ POST back.
        event.move_info.do_move();
        console.log($(this).tree('toJson')); //this will give you the latest tree.
        POSITIONS = $(this).tree('toJson');
        alert(POSITIONS);
        $.post('http://MyServer', {
            tree: $(this).tree('toJson')
        });
        alert("done"); //this will post the json of the latest tree structure.
    }
);


});
```

**3 - Then it should be sent by AJAX**

```
$(function() {
alert("file has been successfully sent");
var data = new FormData();
data.append("custom_css", POSITIONS);
$.ajax({
    url: 'myserver',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        alert("file has been successfully sent");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
    }
});

});
```

**4 - And Finally be received by my servlet and saved to a text file: *Positions.txt***

```
package com.srccodes.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
* Servlet implementation class HelloWorld
*/
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public HelloWorld() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();
    printWriter.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");

    String position = "JQTREE POSITIONS";
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Positions.txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.println(position);
    writer.close();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Your .ajax url should match with @WebServlet() mapping. In your case    `"/HelloWorld"`
> 2. Since you are `POST`ing the data, you should override    `doPost()` method in your servlet.
> 3. Finally in your `doPost()` method,    retrieve the data from `"custom_css"` variable like ..    `request.getParameter("custom_css")`
> 4. Proceed with your rest of    business logic.

---

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/HelloWorld',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
```

---

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getParameter("custom_css")

// Proceed with your business logic here, using above data
//
//
//
//
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't online, but I'm gonna test it right now :) +1

Comment: Sorry, but I still have some doubts: 1 - How do I get the data from `var Positions`, 2 - which directory should I put my page in 3 - Must I export it as a war file and put it in my server (not in my desktop server)

Comment: Tell me anything you need to know about  what I'm doing, I'm searching a lot, but no one talks about the details

Comment: I thought, I gave you answers: request.getParameter("custom_css") will give you var Positions data.

Comment: Deploy this whole thing as a war as you usually do for a web application.

Comment: where do I put the webapp.html in? I don't usually do it because I've never done it successfully :(